# Where does Apache get the value for Perl @INC?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, perl

I run Apache2 server on Debian, user is set `www-data` and also group is `www-data`. When I run Perl CGI-scripts I noticed that their `@INC` differs from scripts I run from command line as same `www-data`-user.

I tried to set `PERL5LIB` environment variable in my site conf, but it did not chage effective `@INC` for Apache:

```
SetEnv PERL5LIB "/home/www/perl5/lib/perl5/i486-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int"
```

From where does get Apache it's `@INC` value?

How could I modify it for my needs?

Comment: Are you running the perl scripts as fastcgi or as plain scripts? Or are you using mod_perl?

Comment: @wurtel Plain old CGI.

Comment: apparently you run into the issue that tainting is enabled by default on cgi scripts (see http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=303052). On that same perlmonks link there is a reference to http://perl.apache.org/docs/general/perl_reference/perl_reference.html#use____require____do_____INC_and__INC_Explained with all info about everthing regarding @INC

Comment: @natxoasenjo: no, tainting is not enabled, i use my own tainting technique. I did not got new information neither from this perlmonks thread nor perlmod docs.